# XDocument.Descendants() versus DescendantNodes()

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I've looked at [Nodes() vs DescendantNodes() usages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850733/nodes-vs-descendantnodes-usages) to see the difference between `.Nodes()` and `.DescendantNodes()` but what is the difference between:

XDocument.Descendants() and XDocument.DescendantNodes()?

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Projects\Fun\LINQ\LINQ\App.config");        
var descendants = xmlDoc.Descendants();
var descendantNodes = xmlDoc.DescendantNodes();

foreach (var d in descendants)
    Console.WriteLine(d);

foreach (var d in descendantNodes)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns only [elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [DescendantNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendantnodes.aspx) returns all [nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx) (including XComments, XText, XDocumentType etc).

Consider following xml to see the difference:

```
<root>
  <!-- comment -->
  <foo>
    <bar value="42"/>Oops!
  </foo>  
</root>
```

`Descendants` will return 3 elements (`root`, `foo`, `bar`). `DescendantNodes` will return these three elements, and 2 other nodes - text and comment.

Answer (score 18):

`Descendants` returns only descendant *elements*, while `DescendantNodes` returns all types of nodes (elements, attributes, text nodes, comments, etc)

So `Descendants()` is equivalent to `DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()`.