# How to prevent duplicate text value output by XElement.DescendantNodes()?

Tags: c#, html, xelement

Problem: `XElement.DescendantNodes()` appears to output some parts TWICE.

Background:

I need to get the entire contents of a `<body>` element to copy to a new html doc within a `<div>` with an embedded style. This is for html mail, where embedded style should work better than a style block because many mail agents strip the `<head>` section. However, I run into the trouble of getting some parts TWICE. How to fix this?

Here is the example input:

```
<body>
  some text
  <a href="http://www.nix.com/index.html">Click Me</a>
  <br />
  <span>more text</span>
</body>
```

This is the output with duplicate strings, otherwise it is exactly what I need:

```
<body>
  <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;">
    some text
    <a href="http://www.nix.com/index.html">Click Me</a>
    Click Me           <<<===duplicate!!!
    <br />
    <span>more text</span>
    more text           <<<===duplicate!!!
  </div>
</body>
```

and this is the code, where I hoped that `DescendantNodes()` should be the correct method to extract both xelement nodes like `<a>` and text nodes like "some text":

```
        using System.Xml.Linq;//XElement

        XElement InputMail = 
            new XElement("body",
                "some text",
                new XElement("a",
                    new XAttribute("href", "http://www.nix.com/index.html"),
                    "Click Me"),
                new XElement("br"),
                new XElement("span", "more text"));

        XElement OutputMail =
            new XElement("body",
                new XElement("div",
                   new XAttribute("style", "font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;"),
                   InputMail.DescendantNodes()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DescendantNodes` will return really *all* nodes, including children, grandchild nodes and so on. That is why you see duplications - inner-most nodes are returned as part of their respective parents, plus as themselves. You need only direct child nodes, and for that you can use:

```
XElement OutputMail =
      new XElement("body",
          new XElement("div",
             new XAttribute("style", "font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;"),
             InputMail.Nodes()));
```

Comment: I still do not understand what could be the use of intentionally returning things twice, but this does solve my problem faster than I could imagine. Great!

Comment: You can use DescendantNodes in certain (quite limited) cases, for example if you want to find all comment nodes inside xml. See here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9851414/5311735 for example.

Answer (score 1):

In VB I would have done it like this

```
    outp.<div>.FirstOrDefault.Add(inp.Nodes)
```

with these declarations

```
    Dim inp As XElement = <body>
                              some text
                              <a href="http://www.nix.com/index.html">Click Me</a>
                              <br/>
                              <span>more text</span>
                          </body>

    Dim outp As XElement = <body>
                               <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px;">

                               </div>
                           </body>
```

Comment: The actual solution is the same as the previous one: just use the Nodes property instead of DescendantNodes. New is the trick of `.<div>` , I haven't seen that before and will certainly try it out in C# some time. Thanks.